# how to use xpath to get all the value conform to requirement from a designated web site

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

there is a website,link:view-source:https://www.zhihu.com/people/weizhi-xiazhi/followers.
and when i use

```
import url
from scrapy.selector import Selector
url = 'https://www.zhihu.com/people/weizhi-xiazhi/followers'
content = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
content = content.decode('utf-8')
Selector(text=content).xpath('' // div[ @class ="ContentItem-head"] // a[@ class ="UserLink-link" and @ target="_blank"]'').extract()[0]
```

to extract the information,there only have a list of 3 element ,which is supposed to have more than 3 element. i wonder why.thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website is loading more followers from javascript after the first query, you could look into selenium for rendering javascript, something like this if you are using phatomJS:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.zhihu.com/people/weizhi-xiazhi/followers')
driver.implicitly_wait(10) #wait some time to load
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="UserItem-title"]/descendant::a')
for e in elements:
    print(e.get_attribute("href"))
```

Note that I opted for a less "restrictive" expression so that it is less sensible to small website changes.

Comment: i try you method  ,and find that waiting some time isn't necessary.using selenium will output all the element anyway.

Comment: The wait is there because sometimes some of the followers will not have loaded yet, and 10sec is def a lot. In actual code, you should wait for some element to show that you are sure will only show when all you want to scrape is loaded in the page. Take a look at this documentation http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: i wonder if there are some methods using requests to reach the same gaol?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to not use selenium + phantomjs? I don't think there is much of a option in this case(maybe splash). If you are looking for a better way to "wait" for the page to load, yes there is: you could search for "selenium explicit wait"

Comment: i mean whether using package 'requests' can reach the same goal. Or is it possible to get the whole page through scrapy.Request

Comment: i want to use scrapy to crawl the website, so i can only use request of scrapy to get the website.